# Backslashes disapearing after my vb.net query to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm having some problems, when I do my query from my vb.net program to my mysql DB the data is sent, but its missing some things, let me explain.

My query is pretty simple I'm sending a file path to my DB so that after I can have a php website get the data and make a link with the data from my DB, but when I send my data the results look like this...

```
    \server_pathappsInst_pcLicences_ProceduresDivers    estCheck_list.doc
```

which should look like

```
    \\server_path\apps\Inst_pc\Licences_Procedures\Divers\test\Check_list.doc
```

I don't know if its my code that's not good or my configurations on my mysql server please help...

Here's my code

```
    'Construct the sql command string 
        cmdString = "INSERT into procedures(Nom, Lien_Nom, Commentaires) VALUES('" & filenameOnly_no_space_no_accent & "', '" & str_Lien_Nom_Procedure & "', '" & str_commentaires_Procedure & "')"

        ' Create a mysql command 
        Dim cmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(cmdString, conn)

        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error uppdating invoice: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try
```

---

Sorry I got a call and could continue my comment so here's the rest :X

Well I guess that would work, but my program never uses the same path since in uploading a file on a server, so this time the document I wanted to upload was this path

```
      \\Fsque01.sguc.ad\apps\Inst_pc\Licences_Procedures\Divers\test\Check_list.doc
```

but next time its going to be something else so I can't hard code the paths, I was looking more of a SQL query which that I might not know, since I already thought about searching my string and if it finds a backslash it adds another one, but I feel its not a good way to script the whole thing...

Anyway thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You're inserting raw values when you should be escaping them. Escape them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you construct the insert SQL it doesn't have the backslashes escaped. For example:

```
INSERT into procedures(Nom, Lien_Nom, Commentaires) VALUES('\\server_path\apps\Inst_pc\Licences_Procedures\Divers\test\Check_list.doc
```

The backslashes need to be escaped like:

```
INSERT into procedures(Nom, Lien_Nom, Commentaires) VALUES('\\\\server_path\\apps\\Inst_pc\\Licences_Procedures\\Divers\\test\\Check_list.doc
```

You can do this with something like (not sure about VB.NET):

```
filenameOnly_no_space_no_accent = filenameOnly_no_space_no_accent.Replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

You should also look into parameterised queries, which may protect you from some SQL injection attacks and are a bit easier to write and maintain compared to stitched-together SQL (this isn't tested and I'm not familiar with MySQL parameterised queries so YMMV):

```
cmdString = "INSERT into procedures(Nom, Lien_Nom, Commentaires) VALUES(?nom, ?lien_nom, ?commentaires)"
Dim cmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(cmdString, conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("?nom", filenameOnly_no_space_no_accent.Replace("\\", "\\\\"))
cmd.Parameters.Add("?lien_nom", str_Lien_Nom_Procedure)
cmd.Parameters.Add("?commentaires", str_commentaires_Procedure)
```

This is based on something I found at this end of [this tutorial](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-4).

Comment: wow thx i got it with the escaped methode ill post my code for futur reference and for others :P

Answer (score 0):

Use double backslashes not single backslash

Answer (score 0):

```
   cmdString = "INSERT into procedures(Nom, Lien_Nom, Commentaires) VALUES(?nom,?Lien_Nom,?Commentaires)"

        ' Create a mysql command 
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(cmdString, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nom", filenameOnly_no_space_no_accent)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Lien_Nom", str_Lien_Nom_Procedure)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Commentaires", str_commentaires_Procedure)


        Try
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error uppdating invoice: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try
```